# Code snippet in R needed to illustrate + operator

Tags: r, function, operators

In R there is the old saying “everything is a function”, even operators like +.  Somewhere I read where they posted some code showing you the function that essentially works behind the scenes when you add A + B, e.g., Y <- A + B.  If someone knows what the snippet of code that does this function in R, can they please repost it here.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a pacakge like `lobstr` to get the abstract syntax tree for R code. For example

```
lobstr::ast(3+9)
# o-`+` 
# +-3 
# \-9
```

Here it shows the expression 3+9 is a call to `+` with parameters 3 and 9. You can do more complicated expressions like

```
lobstr::ast(5*3-6/2)
# o-`-` 
# +-o-`*` 
# | +-5 
# | \-3 
# \-o-`/` 
#   +-6 
#   \-2
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to show this. The most straightforward is calling `+` as a function:

```
`+`(1, 2)
#> [1] 3
```

Alternatively, you can capture an expression like `A + B` and show that it is in fact a call to `+`:

```r
f <- function(x) {
  x <- as.list(match.call())[[2]]
  cat("You have input a", class(x), "to function", as.list(x)[[1]], "with arguments", 
      sapply(as.list(x)[-1], as.character))
}

f(A + B)
#> You have input a call to function + with arguments A B

f(A / B)
#> You have input a call to function / with arguments A B

f(A > B)
#> You have input a call to function > with arguments A B
```